# Default derivation path in Trezor Suite desktop app

Tags: api, trezor

This seems like a silly question but I could not find an answer after searching extensively. I currently have a Trezor Model One device that I'm accessing through both the Trezor Suite desktop app on macOS and the web app at wallet.trezor.io. Looking at the default account generated on the web app, I'm seeing that the xpub associated with the account is different than the xpub associated with the default account generated on the desktop app. I'm also seeing that the web app has the derivation path for the default account as `m/49'/0'/0'` where as the desktop app does not appear to have the derivation path listed anywhere. This remains consistent no matter what type of wallet/account I create (segwit, legacy, etc.). Is the derivation path for the default accounts on the desktop app intentionally hidden from the user?

For context, I'm working on a project that uses the Trezor Connect API to allow a user to fetch the wallet balances for their accounts. Because the derivation path is hidden, there is no way for me to pass the path into the API call to fetch their default account they generated on Trezor Suite. I also tried removing the path from the call entirely which should fetch all of their accounts and prompt the user to select which one they would like to expose but the default account was not listed there, either. (The accounts generated at `m/{49, 44, 84}/0'/0'` were the accounts that appeared when going this route.)

Thanks in advanced for any help!

Comment: Trezor offers a "password" or "hidden" wallet feature to fully exploit the bip39 protocol to generate addresses. However, sometimes people think that it is a necessary password, which is not. Are you trying to use this password? Take into account that the security pin is different from this password. You should use "standard" wallet which doesn't require password and this would just generate the addresses solely from the mnemonic phrase which is the most commonly used case.

Comment: Thank you, @OscarSerna. This was exactly the problem. If you want to post it as a non comment, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trezor offers a "passphrase" or "hidden" wallet feature to fully exploit the bip39 protocol to generate addresses. Think of this as the "salt" in the hashing algorithms.

This means that your mnemonic phrase would have an additional security layer by adding this "salt" or "passphrase" to your privare key.

This feature is really cool, and works great if you are setting up a wallet for the first time in your Trezor. However, Trezor fails at making this clear to the user, which causes that sometimes people think this is a necessary passphrase instead of an optional step. Therefore, when people are trying to reuse a wallet, this additional passphrase will cause the generation of different addresses to the ones that they are expecting.

To avoid this, simply use the "standard" wallet which doesn't require this additional passphrase, and this would generate the addresses solely from the mnemonic phrase which is the most commonly used case.

People often get confused with this passphrase because it is really easy to think that this password is an extra layer of security to access their Trezor, when in reality this is done through a pin number that the user can setup optionally.